# Why does 'Data.List.null' use a 'foldr'?

Tags: haskell

In my beginner perception, one could implement `Data.List.null` as:

```
null [] = True
null _ = False
```

Looking up the actual source in Hackage, I see:

```
null = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True
```

I find this curious, surely I'm missing something I should learn about, but what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`null` is a method of the [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) class:

```
GHCi> :t null
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```

The implementation you quote is [the default one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#Foldable), meant to work for all instances of `Foldable` even if they do not define a specific implementation:

```
class Foldable t where
    -- etc.
    null :: t a -> Bool
    null = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True
    -- etc.
```

The [list instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-278), though, overrides the default implementation:

```
instance Foldable [] where
    -- etc.
    null    = List.null
    -- etc.
```

`List.null`, in turn, [is defined in `GHC.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#null) in the simpler way that you expected:

```
null                    :: [a] -> Bool
null []                 =  True
null (_:_)              =  False
```

Comment: Any reason for `(_:_)` instead of just `_`? To force an error on `undefined` or something?

Comment: @duplode marvellous, thanks, that's what I get for routinely skipping over class declarations and type signatures =)

Comment: @Xeo Good question. I don't know if there is a deeper reason beyond style consistency in that module. Forcing an error on `undefined` isn't necessary -- given that `[]` is matched first, `null undefined` will blow up anyway.

Comment: @Xeo, it doesn't matter for lists, but in other contexts it can be worth the trouble to write out all the constructors. A catch-all case may catch too much by mistake; this is especially likely if someone adds a new constructor to an existing type. A function written `go Red = don'tgo; go _ = gogogo` will do entirely the wrong thing if someone edits the missing `Yellow` constructor into the `TrafficLightColor` type. If instead it matches on both `Red` and `Green`, then `-Wall` or `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` will alert you to the need to add a case.

Comment: Wouldn't a better implementation use "&&" so that the rest of the expression after the first element gets short-circuited?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Do you mean using `(&&)` in the binary operation of that `foldr`? If so, I believe the actual implementation doesn't short-circuit any less than one with `(&&)`. For instance, if the list `foldr` were to be used, we would have `null (x : []) = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True (x : []) = (\_ _ -> False) x (foldr (\_ _ -> False) True [])`, which immediately reduces to `False`.